# Java regular expression for FileNameFilter implementation

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to scan a folder and filter the files which matches a specific regular expression pattern.

***Sample code in the accept method of the FileNameFilter***

---

```
Scanner fileNameScanner = new Scanner(fileName);

Pattern mainPattern = Pattern.compile(this.pattern);

fileNameScanner.findInLine(mainPattern);

MatchResult result = fileNameScanner.match();
```

---

Now, I need a regular expression which filters the file which matches files with names like impl-2.0.xml and at the same time, it should not match impl-Test-2.0.xml.

I tried few settings but does not seem to work. It picks impl-Test-2.0.xml as well.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are looking to match. Are you looking for (pseudocode) `<string>-<major>.<minor>.xml`? If you can describe in words what you are looking for, we can help you write the regular expression.

Comment: *"I have a requirement"*  Good, good..  Do you have a question?  If so, don't be shy, go ahead and ask it. :)

Comment: Give limit examples of what the regex should and shouldn't match.

Comment: Given a set of Strings, i need to have a regular expression which filters strings (files names in my case) of kind impl-2.0 and not impl-Test-4.0.
For example,  i have the following strings and i need to extract only impl-2.0 and api-3.0
Example Strings: 
impl-2.0, impl-Test-2.0, api-2.0, api-Test-2.0, api-temp-2.0.

What is the regular expression that i should use?

Comment: Is this a fair description of the string you are seeking: `<one or more lowercase letters>-<single digit>.<single digit>.xml`? Or are you happy with: `<one or more characters of any type>-<single digit>.<single digit>.xml`? Maybe write your own description using the pseudo descriptions I'm using?

Comment: I am happy with <one or more characters of any type>-<single digit>.<single digit>.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT after comment**
For an absolute path with size number limited

`Pattern.compile(".*impl-[0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]{1,2}.xml");`

For name file :

`Pattern.compile("impl-[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+.xml");`

**EDIT 2**

```
final Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("^\\p{Alnum}+\\-[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+.xml$");
```

Console

```
impl-3.0.xml
api-3.0.xml
x10-2.0.xml
```

You can replace `^` by a Java path separator if you grep an absolute path

Comment: This will not match some of the other examples provided in the comments. Also, it seems a poor choice of pattern for other reasons. You use `{1,}` when you could use `+`. For some reason you've decided the second number can be two digits long, but the first can't? And you accept *anything* before the `impl`, when that might not be appropriate.

Comment: @DuncanJones is my EDIT seems more appropriate for you?

Comment: I have tried these and none of them seem to work **Sample Strings** impl-3.0.xml, api-3.0.xml, x10-2.0.xml, impl-Test-3.0.xml, api-Test-3.0.xml, 4.0-impl.xml **Regular exp** `Pattern.compile(".+-\\d\\.\\d\\.xml") Pattern.compile("\\w+-\\d\\.\\d\\.xml") Pattern.compile(".*impl-[0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]{1,2}.xml") Pattern.compile("impl-[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+.xml") Pattern.compile("\\w-[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+.xml")` It should pick only 3 strings "impl-3.0.xml", "api-3.0.xml", "x10-2.0.xml". May the exp. **impl-[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+.xml** should be generalized.

Comment: @ManikandanKannan with you sample I've found a solution

Answer (score 1):

> I am happy with `<one or more characters of any type>-<single digit>.<single digit>.xml`

"*characters of any type*" is a dangerous statement in regular expressions! It is better if we restrict this by assuming you are happy with any letter or number. Based on that assumption, you want:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+-\\d\\.\\d\\.xml");
```

Which will match characters in the range a-z, A-Z, 0-9 followed by a hyphen, one digit, a period, one digit and `.xml`.

Comment: Matches also `impl-Test-2.0.xml`, `api-Test-2.0.xml` and `api-temp-2.0.xml` which are OP doesn't want. OP doesn't want `<one or more characters of any type>` actually, they wants alphabetical characters I think. Clarification needed.

Answer (score 1):

See it in action on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?31u01):

```
^\w+-\d\.\d\.xml
```

Comment: Should be `^\w+-\d\.\d\.xml`. Otherwise there could be nothing before the hyphen.

Comment: I hereby name this game, Comment Correction Pong! Your turn... :-)

Comment: lol :) Your answer is more complete now. If you consider adding a Regexr link, I put pressure on OP to accept it :)